# Ethereum Block chain with java api for non payment application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, blockchain, ethereum

I'm newer to the blockchain. I'm trying to create a java project for health care backed by ethereum block chain. 
I've looked on web3j which is dealing with payment solution. Another one I found is ethereumj But I didn't found any practical solution.
Anybody please help me on this . I'm looking for the sample non payment application with java and ethereum block chain technology. 
Hi team please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more detail info for your case.
https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1011373
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I have create android application using web3j in android.You can check this on playstore may be this will help you to understand.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=multi.erc20.devgenesis.token.wallet&hl=en

Creating new ethereum wallet

```
     //Path of the folder where you want to save youe wallet keystor or utc file
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + 
        "/.CoinXion";
//passPhrase will be used in future to unlock your wallet file
        String fileName = WalletUtils.generateNewWalletFile(passPhrase, newFile(filePath), false);
     Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                            pass_phrase,
                            filePath+"/"+fileName);
            String publicAddress = credentials.getAddress();
            String privateKey = credentials.getPrivateKey().toString(16);
```

Recovery you wallet from the private key

```
     BigInteger privateBigi = Numeric.decodeQuantity("0x0" + privaeKey);
             ECKeyPair keyPair = ECKeyPair.create(privateBigi); 
    //if you don't want to generate utc file       
             Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(keyPair);
   // or, if you want to generate utc file 
            Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(passphrase,sourceDirectory)
```